# Paypal "Add to cart" HTML form works in Sandbox but not live

Tags: html, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to setup a Paypal form for customers to subscribe to a brunch with 3 separate price ranges depending on the age.

When I test my form by posting the form to `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr`, it works perfectly, but when I try to go live, I get a "GENERIC_ERROR" in the URL and the Paypal window says that "The system is currently not working. Please try again later"

Can you help me ?

Here is my form:

```
<h3>Inscription</h3>
   <form target="_blank" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
      <div class="fields row">
         <div class="form-group small-12 medium-6 columns field field-text ">
            <input name="first_name" id="first_name" type="text" value="" required="true" placeholder="Prénom *">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group field small-12 medium-6 columns field-text ">
            <input name="last_name" id="last_name" type="text" value="" required="true" placeholder="Nom *">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group small-12 columns field field-email ">
            <input name="email" id="email" type="email" value="" required="true" placeholder="e-mail *">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group field small-12 columns field-email ">
            <input name="email" id="phone" type="tel" value="" required="true" placeholder="Téléphone *">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="fields row">
         <div class="form-group field field-select small-12 end columns">
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Brunch Adulte">
            <input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="ADLTBRNCH">
            <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="37">
            <select name="quantity_1" id="Question6" required="true">
                    <option value="" disabled="true" selected="selected">Adultes * (CHF 37.-)</option>
                  <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                </select>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group field field-select small-12 end columns">
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Brunch Junior">
            <input type="hidden" name="item_number_2" value="JNRBRNCH">
            <input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="15">
            <select name="quantity_2" id="Question7" required="true">
                    <option value="" disabled="true" selected="selected">Junior * (CHF 15.-)</option>
                  <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                </select>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group field field-select small-12 end columns">
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name_3" value="Brunch Kids">
            <input type="hidden" name="item_number_3" value="KDSBRNCH">
            <input type="hidden" name="amount_3" value="5">
            <select name="quantity_3" id="Question8" required="true">
                    <option value="" disabled="true" selected="selected">Kids * (CHF 5.-)</option>
                  <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                </select>
         </div>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
      <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
      <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">
      <input type="hidden" name="business" value="robin.vk@yadlo.ch">
      <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="CHF">
      <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="CH">
      <input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://yadlo.ch/">
      <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://yadlo.ch/">
      <div class="form-actions">
         <p class="donation-form_note">* Champs obligatoires</p>
         <button type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary small-10 small-offset-1 columns but end">
               <p>S'inscrire</p>
         </button>
      </div>
      <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif">
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, two variables were missing :

```
<input name="qsID" type="hidden" value="">
<input name="pURI" type="hidden" value="">
```

Everything's works fine now !

Answer (score 0):

did you change from sandbox to:

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
```

Also verify your live creds and check here for further info:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/#checklist

Comment: Hi @Adrianopolis

It is when going from https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr that the problem appears actually…

I will checkout the link you sent

Comment: Well, I have an API key as well, still no luck…